# Why is the TensorFlow Flatten layer not changing the input shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to programming neural networks and using tensorflow and have spent the last day trying to build some simple networks of my own to get practice. I have a shape of (113, 200) that I'm attempting to flatten in the first layer of a sequential network but when the Dense layer runs I receive the error

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 22600 but received input with shape [113, 200]`

I have also noticed that I am recieving the warning

`tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 113, 200) for input Tensor("flatten_input:0", shape=(None, 113, 200), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (113, 200).`

But when I change the input_shape to (None, 113, 200) I receive other errors

Below is my current code

```
model_x = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(113, 200)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(2)
])
model_x.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                optimizer="adam",
                metrics=["accuracy"])

cp_path_x = "TestAITraining/cpx.ckpt"
cp_dir_x = os.path.dirname(cp_path_x)
cp_callback_x = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=cp_path_x, save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)
#model.load_weights(cp_path)
while True:
    model_x.fit(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_arrays, train_pos)), epochs=20)
```

train_array is a (1000, 113, 200) python list before being passed into the dataset and train_pos is a (1000, 2) python list before being added to the data set

Comment: Try without the while loop first. If the input_shape=(113, 200), keras expects training data for the fir (N,113,200), not a single (113,200), so either pack multiple samples within batch, or expand the dims if you really want to train sample-by-sample.

Comment: Also- be aware of the slighlty different shape conventions of SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
model_x = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(113, 200)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
model_x.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                optimizer="adam",
                metrics=["accuracy"])
model_x.summary()
```

**Output**

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 22600)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 64)                1446464   
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 64)                4160      
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 130       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,450,754
Trainable params: 1,450,754
Non-trainable params: 0
```